# Find 2 attributes in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the part of the HTML:

```
<td class="team-name">
<div class="goat_australia"></div>
<a href="http://www.waaaaa.com.au/g-smith/australia/melbourne">Melbourne</a><br />
                            Today
                        </td>
<td class="team-name">
<div class="goat_australia"></div>
<a href="http://www.waaaaa.com.au/g-smith/australia/sydney">Sydney</a><br />
                            Tomorrow
                        </td>
```

So i would like to return all these td tags with the class name "team-name", and only if it contains the text "Today" in it.

My code so far:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, re

starting_url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.mysite.com.au/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(starting_url))                                                                                  

soup2 = soup.findAll("td", {'class':'team-name'})

for entry in soup2:
    if "Today" in soup2:
        print entry
```

If i run this nothing returns.

If i take out that last if statement and just put

```
print soup2
```

I get back all the td tags, but some have "Today" and some have "Tomorrow" etc.

So any pointers? is there a way to add 2 attributes to the soup.findAll function?

I also tried running a findAll on a findAll, that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the structure of the code you've got currently, try looking for "Today" with an embedded findAll:

```
for entry in soup2:
    if entry.findAll(text=re.compile("Today")):
        print entry
```

Comment: You should accept his answer so that he gets rightful credit for helping you out.